# Update mongodb database from python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am having a mongodb database that I want to update. Actually, my code for creating and updating the database is the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['my_db_values']
res = collection = db['db_values']

res = collection.find({"User": "2145"})
if res.count() == 0:
   json_file = {"User": "2145", "Item": {"123456": {"process1": [],"process2": []}}}
   temp_json1 = {"timestamp": "2123532158", "process1_value": 0.4, "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}
   temp_json2 = {"timestamp": "2323532158", "process2_value": 0.2, "P": 0.8}
   json_file ["Item"][str(123464)]["process1"].append(temp_json1)
   json_file ["Item"][str(123464)]["process2"].append(temp_json2)
   temp = db.values
   temp_id = temp.insert_one(json_file).inserted_id
else:
  for line in res:
    counter = 0
    for key in line["Item"].keys():
      if line["Item"].keys()[counter] == "123464":
         collection.update_one({"User": "2145", "Item": {"123464": {"process1":[]}}}, {"$set": {"Item.123464.process2": [
       {"timestamp": "21354879546213", "process1_value": 0,
        "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2,
                         "E": 0.3}}], "Item.123464.process2": [
       {"timestamp": "11354879546213", "process2_value": 0, "P": 0.8}]}})

      else:
         collection.update_one({"User": "2145"},{"$set": {"Item.123464.process1": [{"timestamp": "21354879546213", "process1_value": 0.4, "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}], "Item.123464.process2": [{"timestamp": "11354879546213", "process2_value": 0.2, "P": 0.8}]}})
      counter = counter + 1
```

In the first if stetement if the count it is equally to zero I am creating the json file with that specific user, while if it is already there then i need to do the same for Sla and then I need to update the db with new temp_json1 and temp_json2. How can I update a subdocument into my initial document. Actually I want to perform a check to see if there is in the db a user with the specific id (otherwise I want to add him) then if the current item_id does not exist to add the item in the user document (as I did in my code already). Finally, if the item does exist then I want just to add temp_json1 and temp_json2 in the already created subdocument. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you desire is subdocument querying (querying documents by their nested contents).

You can control this query by using the `$elemMatch` feature, to specify what matches your query by the contents of your `Item` subdocument's `123456` subdocument's `process1` array.

The Mongo Shell format of the query is the following (for python driver just use the query part):

```
db.your_collection.find({ 
   "User": "2145", 
   "Item.123456.process1": {$elemMatch: {$eq: "12345"} }
});
```

So if your collection is populated with the following 2 documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("aaa"), "User" : "2145", "Item" : { "123456" : { "process1" : [ ], "process2" : [ ] } } }                                   
{ "_id" : ObjectId("bbb"), "User" : "2145", "Item" : { "123456" : { "process1" : [ "12345" ], "process2" : [ ] } } }
```

This query will only return the 2nd document, but the omit the first because its process1 array contents don't contain a "12345".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oke probably i wans clear. What I want in the end is that for every different user with different key to have one document with a lot of keys in the header "Item" and I want to add a lot of values there.

Comment: To answer your question of how many times this occurs, you can run a count on this query.
For updating the subdocuments, try reading through this post: https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays

Comment: Can I also insert subdocuments?

Comment: I think you would have to structure subdocument updates as 'upserts', a special type of update, you can read more in the mongodb documentation. It's still a bit unclear what you're trying to do.